# Mimic Database CRUD

Tags: mysql, database, eloquent, mirroring

I want to be able to mimic CRUD of a database without updating any records, but by creating a "mimic session" so that any changes will remain until the session is ended and never pushed live. I'm using MySQL and Eloquent.

Is there any way I could do this? Or perhaps, any applications that can "ghost" or "mirror" a database(s)?

Comment: Wrap everything in a transaction and then roll-back the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Create a clone temp database and use it for the your sessions. This way you can switch between live and test DBs.

Comment: Scenario: I have several databases on different servers, and a staging server which needs to mimic the production environment identically but not perform actual CRUD on data. I would have to clone the entire structure for every session.